# Design Pattern not working with OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I am trying to develop a abstract OnClickListener caller for all my dialog boxes.

```
public abstract class  A {
  public void handleError() {
    if (dialogs != null && activity != null) {
       final String mNoxMessages[] = God.getMnoxMessage((Context) activity, response);
       ((Activity) activity).runOnUiThread(new Thread
           (new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  dialogs.showDialogForMessage("title", "description", 
                  "ok", "cancel",
                  new View.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
//breakpoint location here never reaches
                           performDialogOkAction(response);
                           dialogs.clearAll();
                       }
                  }, 
                  new View.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                         public void onClick(View view) {
//breakpoint location here never reaches
                             performDialogCancelAction(response);
                             dialogs.clearAll();
                        }
                  }
               }));
     );}
   }
   public abstract void performDialogOkAction(Object errorCode);
   public abstract void performDialogCancelAction(Object errorCode);

}


public void showDialogForMessage(String title, String description, 
                     String okButtonText, String cancelButtonText,
                     View.OnClickListener okOnClick,
                     View.OnClickListener cancelOnClick) {

    ok = informationDialog.findViewById(R.id.information_ok);
    cancel = informationDialog.findViewById(R.id.information_cancel);

    ok.setText(okButtonText);
    cancel.setText(cancelButtonText);

    ok.setOnClickListener(okOnClick);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(cancelOnClick);
}


public class B extends A {
 @Override
    public void performDialogOkAction(Object errorCode) {
       //breakpoint location here never reaches
 }
}
```

When I click the button, the control never goes to the `performDialogOkAction` method at all.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: What kind of object is `dialogs` ?

Comment: dialogs.showDialogForMessage is called, even the `setOnClickListener` is called..

Comment: added 2 more locations, breakpoint does not reach inside the onClick, thats the root cause

Comment: I would guess that the downvote is because of the lack of a [mcve]. For example, you've not shown where or how you're using `B`, or what `informationDialog` is or where it's created and shown, or how `A` has access to `response`, even though it's not declared anywhere, etc. Honestly, in its current form, this design seems a little convoluted. Have you considered subclassing `Dialog` or `DialogFragment` and handling all this there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

I was calling this in my main activity, preventing any dialog from doing any action.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        getDialogs().clearAll();
        getDialogs().dimissSnackBar() ;
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Once I commented the above code, I was able to get my onClick events.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the code is not working is because `handleError()` is never called. You have two options here:

1. Replace `handleError()` with constructor `A()`.
2. Call `handleError()` in B's constructor.

Comment: Nope, handleError is called, I put a break point to check.. thats not the issue..

Comment: Is the breakpoint *inside* `performDialogOkAction`?

Comment: yes, the breakpoint is on a statement inside the method